# Strange behavior with async module .map

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

```js
exports.fakeAccounts = function (Account, callback) {
  async.map([{
    username: 'Jehoon',
    provider: 'farcebook'
  }, {
    username: 'C3P0',
    provider: 'farcebook'
  }], function (opts, cb) {
    Account.upsert(opts, cb);
  }, callback);
};
```

Works fine, but

```js
exports.fakeAccounts = function (Account, callback) {
  async.map([{
    username: 'Jehoon',
    provider: 'farcebook'
  }, {
    username: 'C3P0',
    provider: 'farcebook'
  }], Account.upsert, callback);
};
```

throws an error, saying that Account is undefined.

I would have thought that since `Account.upsert` takes the same arguments it would work. I've solved it for now, but I'm wondering what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work because the `Account.upsert` method uses the `this` value and [JavaScript has dynamic `this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword).

You can try binding it explicitly to the this value:

```
exports.fakeAccounts = function (Account, callback) {
  async.map([{
    username: 'Jehoon',
    provider: 'farcebook'
  }, {
    username: 'C3P0',
    provider: 'farcebook'
  }], Account.upsert.bind(Account), callback);
};
```

Comment: This issue is also noted in "Common Pitfalls" on their GitHub readme: https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/master/README.md#common-pitfalls

Comment: Oh cool, I didn't know that @Qantas94Heavy . I guess it's a common problem when using `async` if they have a whole section for it.

Comment: Wow, thanks. Sorry for the dumb question. Hopefully it can save future developers from having to read the docs!